# Sci-fi short story about people inexplicably drawn to a war zone to do battle every few years

Tags: story-identification

Must have read this at least 30 years ago. The protagonist was drawn to a particular location, like many other people, to take part in some pointless war. Presumably, the unknown enemy were others who were also affected the same way but on the opposite side. This happens every few years I think. Also vaguely remember an armored land train during the battle.

The main character meets others who also received the "call" at an inn, and the next day they go off and fight. I think the main character was wounded and carried off in the land train whilst being shelled by artillery. The story is not explicit about where and when it takes place .

Comment: Not much to go on. Please try to remember more details and edit them into your question. (Your description is **vaguely** reminiscent of ["Traveller's Rest"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43952) by [David I Masson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_I._Masson), which you can read [here](http://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/travellers-rest/).)

Comment: By the way, is there anything especially science-fictional or fantastical about the story you describe? Is it set in the future or on another planet? Does it have futuristic weapons or magic or supernatural forces?

Comment: @user14111 By the sound of it, the punchline will be that it was aliens.

Comment: No Aliens and not supernatural except for the calling to assemble for war. Sort of moody piece

Comment: war. Main character meets  others who also received the 'call'  at an inn and the next day they go off and fight. I think the main character was wounded and carried off in the land train whilst being shelled by artillery. Story is not explicit about where and when it takes place .Sorry but it was long ago and these are the only scraps of details that stuck.

Comment: May have found the answer to my own question after much internet trawling.Based on the blurb and reviews 'Out of the Mouth of the Dragon' by Mark S, Geston comes very close though it's a book & not a short story in an sf magazine as I recalled. Now to find a copy & read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the OP's comment above, this was likely *Out of the Mouth of the Dragon* (2003) by Mark Geston.

A [plot summary from goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2660267-out-of-the-mouth-of-the-dragon) shows some matching details:

> Amon VanRoark heard the prophet speaking in the marketplace of the
>   decaying city. Timonias spoke with all the glowing words and crystal
>   clarity of his calling. And the young man listened and he followed.
>   The call was to the Meadows, to the Wars, to the Armageddon in which
>   all the forces of Good and all the forces of Evil would meet, would
>   clash, would decide the fate of the already doomed world. There had
>   been other Armageddons, false ones, so Amon believed, in the lifetimes
>   of his father, and his grandfather before him. But when Amon looked at
>   the ruined world around him, at the lost technologies, the vestiges of
>   dying cultures, the warped rays of the sun, he knew he must answer the
>   call to this last Armageddon, in which Creation would either be
>   renewed or finally be let to end.